# UIButton flickers when pressed

Tags: iphone

I have several UIButtons in my app with different graphics for their On/Off states. The smaller buttons all display correctly without any flickering, but the larger button (320x90px) will flicker a black color over the button when pressed up to 75% of the time. This is on the iPhone, not the Simulator. I've set different combinations of the UIButton's Default,Highlighted,Selected,and Disabled state images in IB but I still cannot get rid of this flicker. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Are you modifying the button at all during the pressed event?

Comment: Once this UIButton is pressed it calls a function that disables the button while processing occurs on a background thread. This is different from the other UIButtons and is probably causing the issue, but I can't get any combination of UIButton state images to prevent the flicker.

Comment: Make sure you don't disable, or for that matter access at all your button or any other interface element from your background thread. That might be causing the issue. Keep in the background thread only processing that does not involve the interface.

Comment: Enabling and disabling the UIButton always happens on the main thread. I know about the UIKit/thread safety issues and have made sure that no UI code is on the background thread.

Comment: I haven't done iOS development for a couple of years now, but I'm pretty sure I tried your solution before posting this question. It does seem to solve the issue for others though so I'll accept it.

Comment: Just to be clear, buttons should change its colour when you press and hold them. Otherwise it's poor UX.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are doing something like `button.selected = !button.selected` in your handler, then I had this problem as well. 
I fixed it calling `button.highlighted = NO`.

Comment: This worked for me. I have a button where the highlighted and selected states use the same image (different from the normal image) and there was a flicker when changing from highlighted to selected.

Comment: David's right, calling `button.highlighted = NO` just before calling `button.selected = NO` (or `button.selected = !button.selected`) fixed the issue for me as well.

Comment: Awesome, haven't bothered to figure this out for the longest time... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Calling `button.highlighted = NO` right before setting `button.selected = YES` works perfectly!

Comment: I have the same issue. Seems to be fixed in iOS7.

Comment: I had the same problem.  It was the drop shadow for me. Once that was removed, no black flickering anymore.

Comment: none of above worked, when i set the property adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false has worked for me